# CSS - modifying background url width

Tags: css

I have the following css `background:#e0e0e0 url(images/bodybg.gif) top center repeat-y;`

What I want to  do is span the bodybg.gif to 100% but i'm not sure how to do that without losing the effect of that tag.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add this to Fiddle?

Comment: You can do it by making a `SVG` image so that it doesn't lose the quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

`background:#e0e0e0 url(images/bodybg.gif) top center repeat-y 100%;`

The number(s) or label for background size can be placed after the background repeat value in a compound `background` style. You may also want to change the background size to `cover` depending on your needs.

[More from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

> The background CSS property is a shorthand for setting the individual
>   background values in a single place in the style sheet. background can
>   be used to set the values for one or more of: background-clip,
>   background-color, background-image, background-origin,
>   background-position, background-repeat, background-size, and
>   background-attachment.

[And on `background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the background
>   images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only
>   partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.
>
> [...]
>
> **cover**: This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `background-size:cover;` property

```
background: #e0e0e0 url(images/bodybg.gif) no-repeat center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* for Chrome et Safari */
-moz-background-size: cover; /* for Firefox */
-o-background-size: cover; /* for Opera */
background-size: cover;
```